# Line Integral with absolute function

Tags: calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I'm trying to solve this line integral:

$$\oint_{L} |x|dxdy$$ $$L: x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
So by dividing the domain into 2 half (left and right) and using Green's Theorem I can solve it.

My question is when dividing a closed domain like this, will it become 2 opened or closed domain? And is there any better way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn'n matter, since integral over one point is equal to zero. It's like $\in_02=\int_0^1+\int_1^2$ and we don't think if it's $[0,1]\cup[1,2]$ or maybe $[0,1)\cup[1,2]$. You can parametrize $L$: $\sigma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$.

Comment: Is this a line integral around the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ or an area integral over the interior of said circle?

Comment: @Mateo I thought if the integral is opened then we must close it with a line (which is y: -1 ∼ 1 in this case)? Either way it equals 0 since the function is only f(x), but if there are any y term in the function then the result would be different right?

Comment: @eyeballfrog it is a line integral around $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Comment: But the integral isn't open. $x^2+y^2 = 1$ defines a closed circle.

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes the circle itself isn't opened, but what I'm trying to do is to split it into 2 halves (since the function is $|x|$), which may make it opened (which is my question).

Comment: Oh, is your plan here to split it into two semicircles, then convert the line integral on each semicircle to an area integral over the interior of the semicircles?

Comment: Um, I believe that splitting a line integral still make it 2 line integral, is this true?